# Variable weakly captured in closure returns nil when capturing itself

Tags: swift

I stumbled upon an odd pattern at work which is very confusing:

```swift
// Foo.swift
class Foo {
    let action: (() -> Void)?
    
    init (action: (() -> Void)?) {
        self.action = action
    }
    
    func doSomething() {
        print("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯")
    }
}

// Bar.swift
var leaky: Foo!
leaky = Foo() {
    leaky.doSomething() // Will print, but have retain cycle
}

// Somewhere in Bar.swift
leaky.action?()
```

If I use `[weak leaky]`, the captured variable will always `nil`:

```swift
// Bar.swift
var leaky: Foo!
leaky = Foo() { [weak leaky] in
    leaky?.doSomething() // leaky is nil, no print will be called
}
```

If I modify `Foo`'s action, it will work normally without a retain cycle:

```swift
// Foo.swift
class Foo {
    let action: ((Foo) -> Void)?

    // ...
}

// Bar.swift
let leaky: Foo = Foo() { param in
    param.doSomething() // Work
}

// Somewhere in Bar.swift
leaky.action?(leaky)
```

I know that in the first snippet, `leaky` is reference itself, so memory leak will happen, but I can't wrap my head around the other 2.

My assumption is that, using `[weak leaky]`, the closure will capture `leaky` before its initialization, while strong reference like the first snippet will use the latest value of the value. Pass it as parameter will only capture the instance until the closure finish, hence no memory leak. Is this correct?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that actually compiles and runs and demonstrates the leak you are asking about.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but isn't the above a reproducible example? https://swiftfiddle.com/244i7vtrtnbxrlpaz3r74wvpru

Comment: Not really. You can't test memory management (leaks) in a playground.

Comment: Agree, but my main question is not about the memory leak, it's about the behavior of capture list and weak reference, furthermore, I have referenced questions before posting, many of which are just snippets, which won't even run in playground

Comment: So does the existing answer solve your problem? If so, accept it and let's move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case leaky isn't initialized and have `nil`, you have captured nil in the closure and have created weak reference to nil.

In the 3rd case you are passing argument, arguments are only captured when closure is called. It's common pattern to avoid retain cycled. For example it's used in RxSwift's binders. I don't know why Apple isn't used it in theirs `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`